# How To Show Exact Decimal Value On Salesforce Dashboard Component?

Tags: reporting, dashboard

I have created one summary report where I am displaying average score in decimals and I have added that report on Dashboard component as follow:

Score displayed on report is **3.67** and on dashboard component it is getting rounded to **3.7** and another thing is in brackets percentage is getting displayed as **(4%)** , I am using "SF Report formula field" to show percentage value on report.

Two Things:-
1. How to display exact score which is displayed on SF Report like **3.67**.
2. How to remove bracket value **(4%)** I only wanted to display **3.67**

[image: Gauge Dashboard Component]

I checked options available by editing dashboard component but I din't see anything which will help me to accomplish above two things.

Please Advise. 
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Change Display Units to Whole Units.**

This is not yet available in Lightning Experience, [vote up the idea here](https://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=0873A000000lDPaQAM).  Try editing in Classic version.

[image]